# Terraform azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription dynamic module

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create a reusable module for terraform resource `azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription` with both `webhook_endpoint` and `service_bus_queue_endpoint_id`

This is my resource

```
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "eventgrid_event_subscription" {
  for_each = { for event_grid_subscription in var.event_grid_subscriptions : event_grid_subscription.eventgrid_subscription_name => event_grid_subscription }

  name                  = lookup(each.value, "eventgrid_subscription_name")
  scope                 = azurerm_eventgrid_topic.eventgrid_topic.id
  event_delivery_schema = var.eventgrid_input_schema

  service_bus_queue_endpoint_id = lookup(each.value, "service_bus_queue_endpoint_id", null)

  webhook_endpoint {
    max_events_per_batch              = lookup(each.value, "max_events_per_batch", null)
    preferred_batch_size_in_kilobytes = lookup(each.value, "preferred_batch_size_in_kilobytes", null)
    url                               = lookup(each.value, "endpoint_url", null)
  }

  included_event_types = lookup(each.value, "included_event_types", null)

  retry_policy {
    max_delivery_attempts = var.max_delivery_attempts
    event_time_to_live    = var.event_time_to_live
  }

  storage_blob_dead_letter_destination {
    storage_account_id          = var.storage_account_id
    storage_blob_container_name = var.storage_blob_container_name
  }
}
```

module code

```
module "eventgrid" {
  source = "../eventgrid" 

  eventgrid_topic_name = "${var.project_prefix}-${var.integration}-egt-${var.environment}-${local.location_abbreviation}"
  resource_group_name  = module.resource_group.resource_group_name
  location             = module.resource_group.resource_group_location

  event_grid_subscriptions = [
    {
      eventgrid_subscription_name = "${var.project_prefix}-${var.integration}-commercetools-algolia-sync-${var.environment}-${local.location_abbreviation}"
      endpoint_url                = "https://${local.function_app_name}.azurewebsites.net/api/commercetools-algolia-sync?code=${data.azurerm_function_app_host_keys.function_app_host_keys.default_function_key}"
      max_events_per_batch              = var.max_events_per_batch
      preferred_batch_size_in_kilobytes = var.preferred_batch_size_in_kilobytes
    },
    {
      eventgrid_subscription_name = "${var.project_prefix}-${var.integration}-order-created-email-${var.environment}-${local.location_abbreviation}"
      endpoint_url                = "https://${local.function_app_name}.azurewebsites.net/api/order-created-email?code=${data.azurerm_function_app_host_keys.function_app_host_keys.default_function_key}"
      max_events_per_batch              = var.max_events_per_batch
      preferred_batch_size_in_kilobytes = var.preferred_batch_size_in_kilobytes
    },
    {
      eventgrid_subscription_name   = "${var.project_prefix}-${var.integration}-order-created-${var.environment}-${local.location_abbreviation}"
      service_bus_queue_endpoint_id = module.servicebus.servicebus_queue_ids[0]
    },
  ]

  storage_account_id          = module.storage_account.storage_account_id
  storage_blob_container_name = module.storage_container_dlq.storage_container_name

  tags = local.tags

  depends_on = [
    module.function_app
  ]
}
```

The module code has a mix of webhook endpoints and servicebus queue id in the block

This works fine with only webhooks but when i add in the servicebus endpoint I get the error

```
Error: "webhook_endpoint.0.url": required field is not set
```

Is there a way to use the same resource and create subscriptions with either webhook endpoint or servicebus queue id from the same module block? In the section where i'm calling the servicebus queue and not the webhook endpoint.. it's still trying to create the webhook endpoint subscriber even though it's null

Comment: used dynamic block with a condition `dynamic "webhook_endpoint" {
    for_each = lookup(each.value, "webhook_endpoint_url") != null ? [1] : []
    content {
      max_events_per_batch              = lookup(each.value, "max_events_per_batch", var.max_events_per_batch)
      preferred_batch_size_in_kilobytes = lookup(each.value, "preferred_batch_size_in_kilobytes", var.preferred_batch_size_in_kilobytes)
      url                               = lookup(each.value, "webhook_endpoint_url")
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, there is a typo when you used dynamic block with a condition, try to replace `webhook_endpoint_url` with `endpoint_url`.

```
dynamic "webhook_endpoint" {     
  for_each = lookup(each.value, "endpoint_url") != null ? [1] : []     
  content {       
    max_events_per_batch              = lookup(each.value, "max_events_per_batch", null)       
    preferred_batch_size_in_kilobytes = lookup(each.value, "preferred_batch_size_in_kilobytes", null)       
    url                               = lookup(each.value, "endpoint_url", null)   
    }   
    }
```